# position div on top of background image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do something that seems like it should be straightforward. I just want to position a div (a rectangle) over a background image. The div will not show as overlaid on top of the background image. The div actually won't show up at all. I've tried using z-index to move the div in front of the image in addition to using position absolute, both with no luck. Here is my html and CSS:

```
<div id="banner-contact">
            <div id="background-contact-info-contact"></div>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#banner-contact{
    width: 100%;
    height:1000px;
    background-image:url('resized-images-logo/contact-page-resized.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    margin:0px;

}
#background-contact-info-contact{
    width:24%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#C16C43;   
}
```

Comment: height:auto; means height=0 in this case ... add a value and you will see it

Comment: Your html is invalid. You have an extra `</div>` that doesn't match anything. Did you copy your code correctly?

Comment: Thanks, giving the height a value worked! Yes, I see the extra div. I think I have just been trying to work on this awhile and I forgot to remove the extra div, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score -1):

`height: auto` means that the height of the div equals the height of it's children elements. Div's are by default auto in height.